# Using OpenCV's findHomography to align scanned documents; How do I avoid obviously-bad (non-planar/3D) transforms?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-registration

We have hundreds of scanned copies of a form;  We need to align each image to a template, correcting for translation and rotation in 2-Dimensions.

After trying some FFT-based methods, we've gotten our best results using OpenCV to do the alignment as described in the article [Image Alignment (Feature Based) using OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/).

When it works, it works perfectly.   But often it produces very strange results.

Sometimes the results are moderately skewed into the 3rd Dimension,  but usually the bad alignments are ridiculous to the point of resembling abstract art.

Is there a way to constrain  findHomography to only planar results?   If not, is there a way to detect non-planar results in findHomography's output?

Screenshots below,  the blue regions are my redactions.

- [slightly skewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF6pp.png)
- [moderately skewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv6wy.png)
- [ridiculously skewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xucZ.png)

Comment: Do you have the `slightly skewed` and the `moderately skewed` images swapped?

Comment: Yes,. Stephen, I did.   Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the least skewed images also have the most blue pixels, and the most skewed images have the fewest blue pixels. Can you determine the amount of skew by simply counting the blue pixels?

Comment: Sadly, the blue pixels are my own after-the-fact redactions of a copyrighted form just before I uploaded it to imgur.    We _could_ do an Image Subtraction from the template, I suppose, but that's more ad hoc than I'd like

Comment: A normal homography will have the xx/yy coefficients close to 1, and the xy/yx close to 0 (exactly 0 if there is no rotation). The coefficients in the denominator should also be small (0 if no perspective). Observe typical values to detect pathological situations.

Comment: Any update on this thread? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @CCC how did you end up solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code but let's say you have `H, matches = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)`. H, in that code snippet, is the homography, a 3x3 transformation matrix. If you multiply a coordinate by the homography the result will be where that coordinate is in the aligned image and then you can do some sanity checks on them.

That said, it is a little more complicated then that. In order to multiply two matrices the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second. So you could multiply a 3x3 matrix by a 3x1 matrix but not a 2x1 matrix. So you need to convert the x,y cartesian coordinate to an x,y,z homogenous coordinate, do the multiplication, and then convert it back to an x,y cartesian coordinate.

In my case I created a `applyHomographyToPoint` function to do that:

```
def applyHomography(coords, H):
  imagepoint = [coords[0], coords[1], 1]
  worldpoint = np.array(np.dot(H,imagepoint))
  scalar = worldpoint[2]
  xworld = worldpoint[0]/scalar
  yworld = worldpoint[1]/scalar
  return [xworld, yworld]
```

It converts a 2x1 matrix to a 3x1 matrix, multiplies it by the 3x3 transformation matrix (homography) and then converts it back to a 2x1 matrix.

The next step is to figure out where on the aligned images the top left coordinate of the original image ended up, where the top right coordinate of the original image ended up, etc. eg.

```
  height, width = im2.shape

  topleft = applyHomographyToPoint([0,0], H)
  topright = applyHomographyToPoint([height,0], H)
  bottomleft = applyHomographyToPoint([0,width], H)
  bottomright = applyHomographyToPoint([height,width], H)
```

Then you can do sanity checks. Like is the top left coordinate still the top left coordinate, is the top right coordinate still the top right coordinate, etc. eg.

```
fudge = 400;
badmatch = false
if topleft[0] + fudge > bottomleft[0]:
  badmatch = true
if topleft[0] + fudge > bottomright[0]:
  badmatch = true
if topleft[1] + fudge > topright[1]
  badmatch = true
if topleft[1] + fudge > bottomright[1]
  badmatch = true
if topright[0] + fudge > bottomleft[0]
  badmatch = true
if bottomleft[1] + fudge > topright[1]
  badmatch = true
if bottomleft[1] + fudge > bottomright[1]
  badmatch = true
if topright[0] + fudge > bottomrigh[0]
  badmatch = true
```

The idea with the fudge variable is that the top left and top right coordinates shouldn't be right next to one another. They can be a variable distance apart but they should be *some* distance apart. What the optimal value is for this fudge variable is ultimately depends on the sizes of the images you're working with.

I think this should handle the moderately skewed and the ridiculously skewed examples. Not sure how well this'll work on the slightly skewed example. For that I'd need an image and a homography that reproduced the slightly skewed example to test it out on.

Also, this won't work so well on documents that were scanned upside down. Like in that scenario the top left coordinate would be the bottom right coordinate, etc, but to keep this post short and sweet (and also since I've spent about as much time on this post as I want to lol) I'll omit code to do that.